# Hardening Apache server

Tags: linux, windows, apache-2.2, security, vulnerabilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips for Securing a LAMP Server.](https://serverfault.com/questions/212269/tips-for-securing-a-lamp-server)

I want to learn about hardening and securing Apache server. Can anybody suggest me very detailed web resource. I also want to learn history of different vulnerabilities existed in Apache, possible attack against them and how to mitigate them. I required this for both Windows and Linux platforms. Anything else which you think I should know from security perspective is welcomed. (I am a student. I don't have industry experience. This question is asked before but I think the answers are for working professionals.)

Comment: I can only laugh on the decision of closing this question for being possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little old most of the points are still valid. There is a part two also the link for which is at the article.

https://www.securityfocus.com/print/infocus/1368

Answer (score 0):

For some basic information and a rogh overview regarding the basics of securing Apache HTTPD for windows you might find this article on [Hardening Enterprise Apache Installations
Against Attacks](http://people.apache.org/~sctemme/ApconUS2008/hardening.pdf) as useful as I did.

Comment: Helpful document to start with but my question is very broad in nature. I am expecting some more detail.