# LAMP Best Practices

Tags: apache-2.2, best-practices, lamp

Does anybody know of a checklist for LAMP best practices?  There is a lot of disparate advice on the 'net, but it would be nice to know if somebody has already published a best-practices guide or book for Linux/Apache/Mysql/PHP hosting architecture before we try to come up with that on our own.

Comment: I think the scope of "LAMP" is possibly too large for one concise body of works because with each piece of the LAMP stack, there's a myriad of possible best practices, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tips for Securing a LAMP Server.](http://serverfault.com/questions/212269/tips-for-securing-a-lamp-server)

Answer (score 2):

I like to think of the LAMP stack as being the "screw your best practices, I'm getting shit done" stack.

So to me the 'best practices' for it are really just overall engineering best practices.   Keep it simple, use the fewest number of moving parts possible, solve the problems you have not hypothetical ones, test, measure, and make metrics-based (or at least informed) decisions, but above all else focus on your business and your customer not your scaling-dreams.

Also, use a CDN on the front and a Percona-on-SSD on the back :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the load you are facing. Each letter in LAMP deserves a book. There are different optimization configuration depending on your goals (scaling horizontally or vertically, latency, throughput).