# Best practices for PHP configuration on shared server

Tags: linux, php, security, shared-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips for Securing a LAMP Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/212269/tips-for-securing-a-lamp-server)

On a Linux based server, what are some of the best practices for securing PHP?

What functions should be disabled (ex. exec, exec_shell, system)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use suhosin - http://www.hardened-php.net/
- Run PHP in cgi/fastcgi mode
- If multiple users are using your webserver, make sure each user's php-cgi processes are spawned under a different (unprivileged) uid/gid pair from its neighbour

Answer (score 0):

mod_php is not a solution because all PHP processes run with the same UID and access rights.

I use [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/) for a shared server. That way all users have their own system accounts and every PHP process is run with their own UID. --> Pro: users have restricted access and are isolated from each other. Con: less performance because it is basically a CGI model.

Stuart Herbert had a blog series about [on this](http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/2008/01/18/using-suphp-to-secure-a-shared-server/) and other PHP setup solutions.