# user and groups for LAMP

Tags: apache-2.2, file-permissions, user-management

I have written [a script](https://github.com/JohnRCrawford/devEnvironment/blob/master/stage1.sh) that installs a LAMP environment and a few other helpful programs.  All of this has been installed under root.

I would now like to create a new user called webmaster that will only be responsible for rendering my website located under: /home/webmaster/htdocs.  As such I have created a new user called "webmaster".

When I run a "ls" on the htdocs folder I get the following output:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 webmaster www-data  1843 Aug 26 21:12 composer.json
drwxrwsr-x  3 webmaster www-data  4096 Aug 26 21:12 src
```

Should the group really be owned by www-data or should I change the group to www-data and then simply add the Apache user, www-data, to the "webmaster" group?  What is the best method with regards to security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would seriously suggest to take a look at a [configuration management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software) for automating and maintaining installations and deployments. Such tools are well tested and are well equipped to handle errors, generate reports and several other tasks in a robust way.
2. I'd question if there's really a need to have a separated `webmaster` user? All *NIX systems already have a user that runs the web server and owns the files to be published (`www-data` in your case). This really boils down to:

   - is this user a system user or
   - is this account meant to be used as login user by somebody/some group?

   If the former, I'd insist there is no real use for such a user.
   If the latter, take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-are-the-best-linux-permissions-to-use-for-my-website) question, which explains in detail how to manage such an environment. [Other solutions](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/) are also valid.
3. With regards to how to secure a LAMP server, read [this Canonical Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/212269/tips-for-securing-a-lamp-server), it addresses that topic in depth.

Comment: I've heard about Chef with regards to the configuration management system and intend to use it sometime in the near future.  Thanks for those links.  As a developer I've never really touched in great detail on admin set-ups before.  Thanks for this info, it was exactly what I needed!