# IPtables locking down website allowing only SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, security, debian, iptables

I have written my first IPtables rule file to try and protect my server on all ports apart from SSH and the ports needed for the web.

This is what I have come up with:

```
i=/sbin/iptables

# Flush all rules
$i -F
$i -X

# Setup default filter policy
$i -P INPUT DROP
$i -P OUTPUT DROP
$i -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
$i -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$i -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Open up ports for nginx
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Make sure nothing comes or goes out of this box
$i -A INPUT -j DROP
$i -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

I know there is somewhat of a black art when it comes to IP tables so I was wondering if anyone could pitch in and see if this is the right approach to securing a web server.

Comment: Ask yourself "how does the reply from server will reach the client?" when you're dropping all outgoing connections.

Comment: Ah, so should I be moving that to the start of the script, so it is later overwritten?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't want to drop all outgoing connections.

You might want to add a rule early on to allow ESTABLISHED connections and if using protocols like ftp you might add RELATED to the rule too e.g.

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

remember rule order matters - first match wins.

You should probably take a look at this Q&A that we have on securing a web server [Tips for Securing a LAMP Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/212269/tips-for-securing-a-lamp-server) it has lots of great information.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Something a bit like this?: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fed516158ec76d3167a8

Comment: @Jimmy http://secopsmonkey.com/base-rulesets-in-iptables.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+secopsmonkey%2FHPJL+%28SecOps+Monkey%29 will help too

Comment: How would you go to only allow outgoing packets that are related to an inbound connection?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` somewhere. Additionally, I would not drop all outgoing packets.

Answer (score 0):

## INPUT chain

Allow new sessions to be created. @Lain's answer have a small problem, it do not perform stateful inspection. This can be achieved by doing the following:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Allow established sessions

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

## OUTPUT chain

### Option #1

Allow all outbound traffic

```
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

### Option #2

Allow only outbound traffic that is replies to acceped input. This can be useful if you want to enforce outbound traffic.

```
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

And an example rule for accepted outbound traffic

```
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

.
.
.

And a final note, keep the rules containing "-m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED" near the top of the ruleset, as they often will be matched against. Rules that initiate sessions will only be used once pr session.