# Is default Apache version in Ubuntu 14.04 secure?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, security

I have installed apache on ubuntu server 14.04 using apt-get. I set up a simple site, uploaded a few pictures etc, the website is working. I've decided to take a look at security of the thing using one of the security checking services online. The security audit says I have 2 medium severity issues:

```
Apache Running Version Prior to 2.4.8
Apache Running Version Prior to 2.4.10
```

The repository does not hold any updates so I'd assume I have highest available version... The only things I knew how to check were openproxy with curl (I tried to fetch a wikipedia page and got my own homepage which seems correct)

1. Should I be concerned by the version of Apache I have available or the security patches are backported and the version is irrelevant here?
2. How can I test for vulnerabilities of the server, what should I look at in particular?

In the logs I saw plenty of ssh brutalforce attempts thwarted by fail2ban and in apache log some strange GET requests (many indicating shellshock attempts) but also the GET requests to other sites, which - as I mentioned - return my homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, don't worry about the old version number.  The Ubuntu packagers backport security patches to older versions.  As of right now, if you run `apt-cache policy apache2`, you should see version 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1 that's sourced from security.ubuntu.com as well as us.archive.ubuntu.com.
2. That's too big a question to answer here.  But see [Tips for Securing a LAMP Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/212269/tips-for-securing-a-lamp-server).

Comment: Almost as you said: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4 0 instead of 4.1 but it's probably minor thing
Thanks a lot. Regarding question 2 - ok, I'll try to look around the web for some resoures, Thank you.

Comment: I added a link to a FAQ here that may help, although it's about hardening, not testing.