# script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/html/r.php

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I have just seen a new series of error in the `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[Thu May 07 17:12:35.433760 2015] [:error] [pid 3488] [client 190.79.132.215:51660] script '/var/www/html/r.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu May 07 17:12:38.066293 2015] [:error] [pid 3471] [client 190.79.132.215:51679] script '/var/www/html/r.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu May 07 17:12:43.523091 2015] [:error] [pid 3474] [client 190.204.156.103:59542] script '/var/www/html/r.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu May 07 17:12:45.213665 2015] [:error] [pid 3451] [client 190.204.156.103:59568] script '/var/www/html/r.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu May 07 17:12:50.660274 2015] [:error] [pid 3472] [client 190.204.156.103:59592] script '/var/www/html/r.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu May 07 17:12:51.354739 2015] [:error] [pid 3473] [client 82.8.22.23:49205] script '/var/www/html/r.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu May 07 17:12:51.512948 2015] [:error] [pid 3446] [client 82.8.22.23:49206] script '/var/www/html/r.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu May 07 17:12:51.669047 2015] [:error] [pid 3488] [client 82.8.22.23:49207] script '/var/www/html/r.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu May 07 17:12:51.838961 2015] [:error] [pid 3471] [client 82.8.22.23:49208] script '/var/www/html/r.php' not found or unable to stat
```

`r.php` doesn't exist.

This server is running Ubuntu 14.04 in a LAMP setup.

I have never seen this sort of attack before, should i be concerned or securing my system in any way for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like someone is scanning your website on different ports and looking for a specific file (*r.php*) which could be a backdoor or something similar. As the file does not exist it throws errors (which is good)...  I see this kind of log entries from time to time as well.

Stick to these answers on how to secure LAMP in general: [Tips for Securing a LAMP Server](https://serverfault.com/a/212462/71626)